# Saving class including a container with pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

I am writing a program that has a 'base' class called `Group`. The class will have only one instance. Aside from some properties and methods, it needs to keep track of a variable amount of `group_companies`.

After working with the program (that may involve adding or deleting `group_companies`), I want to save the current state of my work to a file, which can be imported in the next session. I read that `pickle` can be used for that and even for 'pickling' classes. I have seen similar questions but none answering my question, or yet too complicated for me to be understood.

I came up with the following solution hereunder that seems to work.

Is there a better approach than my solution? I tried to define the `group_companies` as a class variable, but then it won't 'unpickle' (the `group_companies` dictionary remains empty).

The next step will involve changing the `group_companies` from dictionaries to classes themselves. Will that still work?

That you for your help and insights.

```py
import pickle


class Group():
    """ Creates a group, its metadata and its methods. """

    def __init__(self, name, rates):
        self.name = name
        self.rates = rates

    def add_group_company(self, name, descriptor):
        try:
            self.group_companies[name] = descriptor
        except Exception:
            self.group_companies = {}
        self.group_companies[name] = descriptor

    def __repr__(self):
        return "This is group {}".format(self.name)

# Initialize some variables
group_name = 'XYZ'
rates = {'EUR': 1.0000,
         'USD': 1.2364,
         'NOK': 8.3254,
         }

# Create a group and add some group_companies
group = Group(group_name, rates)
group.add_group_company('ABC', 'some data')
group.add_group_company('DEF', 'moar data')


# pickle the class
with open('data', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(group, f)

# Delete class instance and test if succesfully deleted
del(group)
try:
    print(group)
except Exception:  # catchall
    print("Variable appears no longer to exist.")

# Unpickle my class
with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    group = pickle.load(f)

# Test the results (satisfactory)
print(group)
print(group.group_companies)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pickle` module is fine for such a use case, you just have to be
aware of [its limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

In particular you'd run into problems in case the current class
definition doesn't match the one of the stored object any more, even
something like a renaming of the class is problematic.

> Is there a better approach than my solution? I tried to define the
> `group_companies` as a class variable, but then it won't 'unpickle'
> (the `group_companies` dictionary remains empty).

Well, unless you meant to do a class variable it's fine as it is.  At a
glance I wouldn't expect that `pickle` on an object of a class would
write out *class* properties anyway, so this all seems like it should
be.  (It wouldn't make sense to write out class properties every single
time an object that's simply an instance of the class is being pickled,
not to mention reading that data back in every single time.)

> The next step will involve changing the `group_companies` from
> dictionaries to classes themselves. Will that still work?

Presumably you'd create a `Company` class and add that to the
dictionary?  That'd work.  Or if you mean you'd change `group_companies` from a
dictionary to an object, yes, sure, that will work fine as long as the
`pickle` module understands the objects (which it will in this case).

That said, the code looks fine.  Two small things I'd perhaps change:

- Consider using `__str__` instead of `__repr__` and the difference in
  output between `group` and `print(group)` in the REPL

  (`This is group XYZ` and `<__main.Group object at 0x...>` for the
  `__str__` variant).  `repr` should return the "canonical string
  representation of the object.  [...] eval(repr(obj)) == obj."  That's
  a good guideline for how it should behave, while `str` is simply for
  the printed representation of the object (my words, couldn't find a
  quote quickly).
- `self.group_companies` should be initialised from the start in
  `__init__`.  This simplifies `add_group_company` greatly and will
  ensure the object is already in a "valid" state from the start.

Btw. `del` is a statement, so `del group` is a bit more explicit in what
it does, removing the `group` name from the local variable bindings.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. For me as beginner, and not having much feeling with practice I do appreciate your insights.